Bytes shuffled more than bytes processed in BigQuery
I have two BQ tables that have the same data, one has yearly partitions on a date field while the other has no partitions. I ran the same query against both the tables, basically a simple Select all query for a specific year. The following execution details are available for the two queries:




Un-Partitioned Table
Partitioned Table




Bytes Processed
~100 GB
~25 GB


Bytes Shuffled
~85 GB
~85 GB



The Bytes processed make sense, but I do not understand the bytes shuffled. For both the tables, the total logical bytes are the same (~103 GB), and the physical bytes  are ~6 GB for the un-partitioned table and ~4 GB for the partitioned table.
Why are the bytes shuffled so big, nearly the same as the total logical bytes? In the case of the partitioned table, 25 GB is about the size of the partition for a year, so the bytes processed seem reasonable but the bytes shuffled are the same as that for the un-partitioned table, what could be the reason for that?

To my understanding, the concept of Bytes Shuffled is a function of the amount of data that has to be moved between compute processors to come up with a result.  Imagine SELECT * FROM X WHERE A=B ORDER BY Y
The WHERE A=B filter reduces the result set.  The partition vs unpartitioned determines how much disk to read.  However, the result set will be the same size based on the filter.  To sort, a shuffle must occur.   When we see your execution plan, we should be able to learn why the shuffles are happening.
